# Core-plot grid lines with LabelingPolicyNone

Tags: core-plot

I have custom labels for which I used the LabelingPolicyNone. But with that labeling policy I can't get to show grid lines.

Is there a way to show grid lines with LabelingPolicyNone?

Answer (score 0):

The grid lines are shown at the tick locations. Set the `majorTickLocations` and the `majorGridLineStyle`. If you don't want tick marks at the same locations, set the `majorTickLineStyle` to `nil`.